# How to round and apply min and max to all values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I'm struggling on how to clean-up a dataframe.  What I would like to do is truncate all items (i.e. floor()), and for any items below or over a min/max, replace with the min or max as applicable.  E.g. for this dataframe:

[image]

If my min and max are 1 and 5 respectively, 1.2 would truncate to 1, 9.6 would map to 5, -1.2 would map to 1, and 3.5 would truncate to 3:

[image]

Other than brute-force iteration using iterrows(), I haven't been able to get this to work.  Lots of stuff on *finding* the min and max, but not on applying *a* min and max.

May I please ask if anyone has some suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `applymap`, such as:

```
from numpy import floor

MAX, MIN = 5, 1

df = df.applymap(lambda val: MAX if val > MAX else int(floor(val)) if val > MIN else MIN)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I was trying df.apply(lamba x: 1 if x < 1 else x) and that was giving me errors; I hadn't heard of applymap().  using applymap() in my code instead of apply() worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) and cast to [`int`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1.2, 3.5],
    'B':[9.6, -1.2]
})
df.clip(1,5).astype('int')
```

Out:

```
   A  B
0  1  5
1  3  1
```

If you want `float` values you can `floor` the dataframe with `np.floor`, which conveniently returns a `pd.dataframe` and then `clip`.

```py
import numpy as np

np.floor(df)
```

Out:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  9.0
1  3.0 -2.0
```

```py
np.floor(df).clip(1,5)
```

Out:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  5.0
1  3.0  1.0
```

---

### Micro-Benchmark

With `python 3.6.9`, `pandas 1.1.5` on a google colab instance

Results:

[image: benchmark results]

Code used for the benchmark

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import perfplot

def make_data(n=100):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.uniform(-1.2, 9.6, (n,10))
    )

def clip_castint(df):
    return df.clip(1,5).astype('int')

def clip_npfloor(df):
    return np.floor(df.clip(1,5))

from numpy import floor
def applymap(df):
    MAX, MIN = 5, 1
    return df.applymap(lambda val: MAX if val > MAX else int(floor(val)) if val > MIN else MIN)

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_data,
    kernels=[clip_castint, clip_npfloor, applymap],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(10,22)],
    xlabel="df(rows, 10)"
)
```

Comment: Thanks; I tried using np.floor(df.clip(1,5)) as an example and that works as well.  I will have to try this vs. applymap() to see which performs better.

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks.  For my small dataset it made no difference but I will keep this in mind for larger sets.